# Installation of this product requires operating system supplemental language support

Tags: installation, language

I'm trying to install Sharepoint foundation 2010 in a Windows 7 enviroment, following the steps of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28office.14%29.aspx. But when I start the step

> C:\SharePointFiles\Setup.exe

I get this error:

> "El idioma de este paquete de instalación no es compatible con su
>   sistema".

Here is the log:

> PERF: TickCount=168737561 Name=OBootStrapper::Run Description=Begin
>   function Operating System version: 6.1.7600 . Platform ID: 2 Running
>   64-bit setup on a 64-bit operating system. Command line:
>   "C:\SharePointFiles\setup.exe"  No command line arguments given
>   Parsing config.xml at: config.xml Parsed setting: UsingUIInstallMode
>   with value: 1 in config.xml. Parsed setting: SETUP_REBOOT with value:
>   Never in config.xml. Parsed setting: AllowWindowsClientInstall with
>   value: True in config.xml. Parsed setting: SETUPTYPE with value:
>   CLEAN_INSTALL under package: sts in config.xml Logging type verbose
>   specified in config.xml. Log directory:
>   C:\Users\USERTO~1\AppData\Local\Temp specified in config.xml Log file
>   template: Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 Setup *.log specified
>   in config.xml DATADIR: "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Data" specified in config.xml. Log
>   level changed from: Standard to: Verbose Searching for best setup
>   controller dll to load... Checking for setup controller dll at
>   [C:\SharePointFiles\Updates]. Checking for setup controller dll at
>   [C:\SharePointFiles].   Found setup controller dll at
>   [C:\SharePointFiles\WSSSETUP.DLL].   Version [14.0.4755.1000]. Verify
>   file signature in "C:\SharePointFiles\setup.exe"
>   C:\SharePointFiles\setup.exe is trusted. Verify file signature in
>   "C:\SharePointFiles\WSSSETUP.DLL" C:\SharePointFiles\WSSSETUP.DLL is
>   trusted. Using setup controller dll at
>   [C:\SharePointFiles\WSSSETUP.DLL]. PERF: TickCount=168737670
>   Name=OBootStrapper::Run Description=Calling RunSetup
>
> PERF: TickCount=168737670 Name=RunSetup Description=Begin function
>   Catalyst execution began: 07/03/2013 08:30:46. Parsing config.xml at:
>   config.xml Parsed setting: UsingUIInstallMode with value: 1 in
>   config.xml. Parsed setting: SETUP_REBOOT with value: Never in
>   config.xml. Parsed setting: AllowWindowsClientInstall with value: True
>   in config.xml. Parsed setting: SETUPTYPE with value: CLEAN_INSTALL
>   under package: sts in config.xml Logging type verbose specified in
>   config.xml. Log directory: C:\Users\USERTO~1\AppData\Local\Temp
>   specified in config.xml Log file template: Microsoft SharePoint
>   Foundation 2010 Setup *.log specified in config.xml DATADIR:
>   "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\Data" specified in config.xml. Setupexe Resiliency Mode
>   is set to [DoNotPerform]; thus Resiliency is [disabled] for the
>   [InstallExecutionMode] Searching for default versions of resource
>   files under the folder [C:\SharePointFiles]. Found [0] resource files
>   under the default folder. Resource File Manager : Current user's LCID
>   is [3082]. Resource File Manager : error : ResourceFileManager does
>   not contain at least one ResourceFile. Unable to find best match
>   ResourceFile for CultureTag=[es-ES]. Unable to locate a suitable
>   resource file which contains resources that match the current user's
>   Locale [3082]. Checking the value of
>   'Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\LanguageResources[PreferredSetupLanguage]'
>   Resource File Manager : error : Resource file not found for CultureTag
>   [en-US]. Unable to select the language in which to run setup because
>   no setup resource file(s) were located. Preparing to prompt user to
>   select the language in which to run setup.exe in (i.e. the culture of
>   the resource file to load.) SELECT_CULTURE : Initializing
>   OSelectCulture UI... SELECT_CULTURE : error : ResourceFileManagerPtr
>   has no language(s) for user to select from. Error: Installation of
>   this product requires operating system supplemental language support.
>   ErrorCode: 0(0x0). Failed final attempt to load a setupexe resource
>   file. Error: Installation of this product requires operating system
>   supplemental language support. Type: 54::NoSupportedCulture.
>
> Showing parent-less message Title: 'Setup Error', Message: 'El idioma
>   de este paquete de instalación no es compatible con su sistema. '
>   Message returned: 1 Catalyst execution finished: 07/03/2013 08:30:47. 
>   Return code: 30054.  Exception caught: NoSupportedCulture. PERF:
>   TickCount=168738855 Name=RunSetup Description=End function
>
> Setup temp folder set to
>   [C:\Users\USERTO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Setup000020b8].

I have downloaded the spanish version, uninstalled office 2010 plus. But I have the same error.

Comment: Do you have spanish language support for SharePoint installed?

Comment: I have no matter to install it in english, but i cant install it

Answer (score 1):

When you Install SQL Server 2008 The system asks specifically for the Spanish (Spain) language (Español - España). So, maybe the isse is similar. You have to go to region settings and put that language before attempting to install again.

You can check is this helps.

Comment: I have try it but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem extracting the files and it didn't create de folder wss.es-es, that was the source of the problem. So i solve the extraction problem and it appears